# DropDown Login form for bootstrap 3.0

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure if this works for 3.0, but this is the one im following:http://mifsud.me/adding-dropdown-login-form-bootstraps-navbar/

I'm using ruby on rails 4.0  and this snippet of code is my from my views/layouts/_header file

```
<header class = "navbar  navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse ">
  <div class = "navbar-inner">
  <div class = "container">
<%= link_to "InYourShoes" , '#', id: "logo" %>
<nav>
 <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><%= link_to "Home", '#'%></li>
   <li><%= link_to "Help", '#'%></li>
   <li><%= link_to "Sign up", '#'%></li>
   <li class = "dropdown">
    <a class = "dropdown-toggle" href = "#" data-toggle = "dropdown"> Sign In<strong class "caret"></strong></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" style = "padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
     <form action="[YOUR ACTION]" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user[username]" size="30" />
        <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="user[password]" size="30" />
        <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
        <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
       </form>
      </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>
```

after browsing around for solutions i found a old post relating to this but i have no idea where to these 2 lines of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

and

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   //Handles menu drop down`enter code here`
   $('.dropdown-menu').find('form').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
  });
  </script>
```

This is my first website, and i appreciate the help. I know rails has coffescript but i never got around a tutorial that used it yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application.html.erb file you can put script elements in head.

```
<head>
<title>.....</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   //Handles menu drop down`enter code here`
   $('.dropdown-menu').find('form').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
```

However javascript are generally written in the app/assets/javascript directory and then imported with this code <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %> in the head tags of application.html.erb file.

**EDIT:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I tried using these two js files instead and they worked for me, jquery from google and the whole bootstrap javascript file from [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

To get "InYourShoes" to be aligned in the left you can use :class => "navbar-brand".

```
<%= link_to "InYourShoes" , '#', id: "logo", :class => "navbar-brand" %>
```

Comment: i added the lines into my application file and when i click the signin button, the dropdown still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change the two javascript files to the ones i added in my answer and it should work.

Comment: If you want you "InYourShoes" to be aligned in the header add the code a provided in my answer. :)